# Linking error when using NVIDIA's static PTX compiler library & -lpthreads

Tags: cuda, pthreads, linker-errors, libstdc++, ptx

I'm linking a program using NVIDIA's PTX compiler library, with a link command generated CMake, like so:

```
usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG \
    CMakeFiles/vectorAdd_ptx.dir/modified_cuda_samples/vectorAdd_ptx/vectorAdd_ptx.cpp.o \
    -o bin/vectorAdd_ptx  \
    -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/stubs \
    /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libcudart.so \
    -lpthread \
    /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvrtc.so \
    /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so \
    /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a
```

or rather, a GitHub Actions Ubuntu 20 VM is linking my program this way. This command yields the following output:

```
usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx989':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx2472':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18096':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18072':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x169): undefined reference to `sem_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18073':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x1ce): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18075':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference to `sem_trywait'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18035':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x262): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x26f): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x284): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx2045':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x384): undefined reference to `sem_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx2133':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x425): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18094':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x4cc): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18102':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x528): undefined reference to `sem_init'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x56e): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x591): undefined reference to `sem_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x5a8): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx2076':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x632): undefined reference to `sem_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18099':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x6b9): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x6e2): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18101':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x7ce): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx14389':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x836): undefined reference to `pthread_attr_setstacksize'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x862): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx17995':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x939): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x962): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx17967':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0xb7e): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx17962':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0xbbf): undefined reference to `sem_post'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18098':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `sem_post'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18097':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `pthread_kill'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18074':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `sem_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18076':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x221): undefined reference to `sem_post'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx2045':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x39d): undefined reference to `sem_post'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libn
vptxcompiler_static.a(ptxtmp245.o): in function `__ptx18094':
stdThreads.cpp:(.text+0x4ea): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't quite understand what's going on. I *have* linked against the pthreads library, haven't I? And - where does `stdThreads.cpp` come from? The standard library, or the NVIDIA PTX compiler library? Perhaps I need to link against pthreads different because `libnvptxcompiler_static.a` is a static library?

I'll mention that when I build this program on my own system (Devuan Daedalus), the link command is:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -g \
    CMakeFiles/vectorAdd_ptx.dir/modified_cuda_samples/vectorAdd_ptx/vectorAdd_ptx.cpp.o \
    -o bin/vectorAdd_ptx  \
    /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so \
    /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnvrtc.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so \
    /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnvptxcompiler_static.a
```

(it's generated by CMake, then broken up into multiple lines to fit the width here), and it succeeds.

Comment: Linking statements are read left to right. Specify the dependency *after* the library which requires it, not before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### tl;dr: In your `CMakeLists.txt` file, place a pthreads library dependency *after* the PTX compiler library dependency.

(Thanks goes to @talonmies for this.)

When a library `lib1` uses symbols from `lib2`, not defined in `lib1`, the linker can only resolve these symbols if it sees `lib2` *after* it has seen lib1, i.e. to the *right* of `lib1` on the command-line. In your case, you likely have a CMake `target_link_libraries()` arrangement in which a dependency on `lib2` is considered before the dependence on `lib1` - and placed on the command-line before `lib1`. Example:

```
target_link_library(lib1 Threads::Threads)
target_link_library(lib2 lib1 libnvprofiler_static)
```

you need to rearrange this CMake code so that, upon resolution, `CUDA::nvptxcompiler_static` appears before `Threads::Threads` as a dependency, e.g.

```
target_link_library(lib1 Threads::Threads)
target_link_library(lib2 libnvprofiler_static lib1)
```